# If I do not have access to casein protein, is there a hack I can do with whey protein isolate to make it digest more slowly?

Tags: nutrition, muscle-gain, muscle-recovery

As I already understand, the benefit of casein protein is that it is slow absorbing, and hence able to keep our bodies in a positive nitrogen balance over an extended period of time. This makes it optimal for nighttime recovery.

However, if I do not have access to casein protein, is there a hack I can do with whey protein isolate to make it digest more slowly, thereby providing the same benefits as casein regarding overnight muscle recovery? eg take it with high fibre food?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure that this question technically qualifies as being on topic or not, but consuming anything else will slow down the rate of digestion. So fiber, fat, or whatever else you decide to consume would do the job. I’m assuming that this question is in regards to body composition as it relates to rates of muscle protein synthesis.